# ESRI ArcGIS TimeSlider issue with multiple Feature Layers (using ArcGIS API for WPF)

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

I am using ArcGIS API for WPF for my mapping application and my goal in this mapping application is to display time aware featurelayers and then use a TimeSlider (ESRI TimeSlider) to change the Time Extent of the layers. I am using the following two layers provided by ESRI.

http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Earthquakes/Since_1970/MapServer/0

http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hurricanes/NOAA_Tracks_1851_2007/MapServer/0

I am using ESRI TimeSlider as follows.

```
 <esri:TimeSlider x:Name="GTTimeSlider" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
                        TimeMode="TimeExtent"
                        MinimumValue="{Binding LayerTimeExtentStart,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        MaximumValue="{Binding LayerTimeExtentEnd,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        Value="{Binding LayerTimeExtent,Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Intervals="{Binding LayerTimeIntervals, Mode=OneTime}" BorderBrush="White"                    Background="{x:Null}" >

        </esri:TimeSlider>
```

The properties `LayerTimeExtent`, `LayerTimeExtentEnd` and `LayerTimeExtentStart` are set in the ViewModel for the `TimeSlider`. These values are initialized based on the TimeExtent of the feature layers which I mentioned above when they are added on the map. Using DataBinding I have bound these properties to the BaseMap using:

```
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("LayerTimeExtent");
    myBinding.Source = this;
    map.SetBinding(Map.TimeExtentProperty, myBinding);
```

The issue arises when I add both layers at the same time to the map. Although both layers initialize their own TimeSliders but changing the value of `TimeSlider` on one layer dialog box changes the `TimeExtent` value on the other layer as well as both are on the map at that moment and the map `TimeExtentProperty` is bound to the Value of `TimeSlider`. Is there a work around for this problem?

Here is a screenshot of the TimeSlider View along with the layers added on the basemap.

[image]